# Specialist Improved Thermal Binocular - How to tag enemies?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

I improved my Thermal Binocular for the Specialist class to be able to tag enemies to help my teammates, but what a pain!

So I don't know if it's buggy, if I don't know how to works or if I'm so bad at it, but I don't to tag a lot of people! (For now, I'm considering the last two options, leaning towards the third one...)

What I understood to be able to tag someone: You go in Binocular mode (third ability - R1 on PS4), you use the binocular (L2 on PS4) and see a thermal signature of the world (green with yellow enemies). You then point the center cross to an enemy and press "shoot" (R2 on PS4). The enemy has to be in line of sight, i.e. not hidden by a wall, an object or anything else. In fact, it show you his red class tag above him.

However, it looks like the tagging itself is quite random.
I don't know if you have to press R2 for some time before the tagging takes effect, keeping the guy in the crosshair. It also seems to be a (long) recharge delay after each tag.

Do I miss something? Did I get it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this star card that much, but when I have, I've learned that it works best when there are multiple enemies in the line of sight. You can tell that they are in the line of sight because you can see the class indicator above their head. Then hold the fire button down and it should mark them.

I used the binoculars more in the first game, when it worked in a similar way, and there would be a small circle on enemies that could be tagged, and when you held the fire button down it would fill up and they would be marked, and my guess is that in the more recent installment it works in a similar way.